# Mirror a file in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to work on making a new site and I want to be able to mirror a site. Below is an example:

User visits: `https://example.com/items/{some child folder}`

User sees this file mirrored: `https://example.com/items/listing.php`

I want user to be able to see that file, but, when doing so, it don't want it to redirect. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
I found a solution to the above problem. However, I need another question fixed. How would I stop the file `listing.php` in the `/products` folder from following the redirect?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/(.*) index.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Kindly do share your htaccess rule file in your question, which you have tried, thank you.

Comment: I've not been able to successfully find any examples for this. Unsure if it's just me being slow today, but, it's just not making a lot of sense to me @RavinderSingh13

Comment: You want to implement an internal rewriting rule. That is not a redirection as it will not change the URL visible in the browser and does not require a second request. Take a look at the documentation of the rewriting module the apache http server brings along. It comes with great examples, I am sure you will be able to implement this yourself: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: @arkascha I've taken a look on there and I'm not seeing a great way to do it. I found a solution that would "work", however, it's got an issue. I want to still be able to know what file the user traveled to. If I trying and echo the dirname, it shows the file it was rewritten to and not the actual location.

Comment: Please take a look into the "superglobal" variable php offers: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php Especially the content of `$_SERVER` and `$_REQUEST` should be of interest for you.

Comment: @arkascha I managed to find a solution. If you look in the question, it's been updated. However, there is another issue posed. How would I exclude a certain file from following the rewrite?

Comment: Well, take a look at the `RewriteCond` directive in the documentation I posted above.

Comment: "I want user to be able to see that file" - But the example you gave is "{some child folder}", not a file?

Answer (score 1):

> How would I stop the file `listing.php` in the `/products` folder from following the redirect?
>
> ```
> RewriteRule ^products/(.*) index.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
> ```

Be more specific in the regex. If your products don't contain dots in the URL-path then exclude dots in the regex. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^products/([^./]+)$ index.php?name=$1 [L]
```

The above assumes your product URLs are of the form `/products/<something>`. Where `<something>` cannot consist of dots or slashes (so naturally excludes `listing.php`) and must consist of "something", ie. not empty.

Unless you specifically need the `NC` flag then this potentially opens you up to duplicate content.

If you want to be explicit then include a *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/products/listing\.php$
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)$ index.php?name=$1 [L]
```

The `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the root-relative URL-path, starting with a slash. The `!` prefix on the *CondPattern* negates the regex.

Or, use a negative lookahead in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, without using a *condition*. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^products/(?!listing\.php)([^/]+)$ index.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html